# php PDO result from stored procedure are empty

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Here are one example:

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp(
  IN in_var VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN

     -- This is to avoiding the next problem:
     -- If I USE bellow: EXECUTE USING in_var NOT WORK
     -- But IF I USE: EXECUTE USING @user_invar WORKING GOOD
     SET @user_invar = in_var;

    SET @query = "SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column = ? LIMIT 1;";

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @user_invar;
     SET @founded_rows = FOUND_ROWS();
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF(@founded_rows = 0)THEN
        SELECT 'ZERO_REZULTS' AS RESULTS;
    END IF;  
END;
```

PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO( $connection_params );

$sql = "CALL my_sp( :in_var )";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute( array( ':in_var' => $_POST['in_var'] ) );
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//No errors but $rows is an empty array if @founded_rows is 0
//espected RESULTS = ZERO_REZULTS
```

The strange thing is that if I execute the procedure my_sp() from phpmyadmin interface the procedure working as espected. I got:

```
RESULTS = ZERO_REZULTS
```

**EDITED:**

**In addition of the @Bill Karwin answer, to working as espected the procedure must have the last `SELECT` inside stmt like that:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp(
  IN in_var VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN

SET @user_invar = in_var;

SET @query = "SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE my_column = ? LIMIT 1;";

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @user_invar;
SET @founded_rows = FOUND_ROWS();
IF(@founded_rows = 0)THEN
    SELECT 'ZERO_REZULTS' AS RESULTS;
END IF;  
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

END;

Comment: anything from error reporting and pdo error handling?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No errors Result in php is Ok but empty array.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the procedure returns a different number of columns depending on whether the first `SELECT` returns something or not.

Comment: Try changing the `IF` so it returns the same number of columns as the first query.

Comment: @Barmar so you suggest to use `NULL AS real_fields .... 'NO_RESULT' AS RESULT` ?

Comment: It's just a guess, I'm not sure it's the real problem.

Comment: Ok I will try. (the guess are welcome :) )

Comment: Are you sure you need the second `SELECT`? Why not just have the caller count the number of rows returned by the procedure?

Comment: There are only one little example. I try to use `IF(@founded_rows = 0)THEN` ... many times as condition in the real procedure

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with prepared statements in MySQL stored procedures, but I could swear their results do not get added to the result sets of the procedure they are called in. I seem to recall needing to have the prepared statements insert into a temporary table that the proc can select from after the statement is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion that the queries need the same number of columns is not the problem. Stored procs generate multiple distinct result sets, not a UNION.

The first SELECT produces a result set of zero rows. You still have to `fetchAll()` to consume this rowset, even though it's "empty." Then you have to use `nextRowset()` to advance to the next rowset returned by the proc.

```
$dbh = new PDO( $connection_params );

$sql = "CALL my_sp( :in_var )";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute( array( ':in_var' => $_POST['in_var'] ) );

do {
    $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($rowset) {
        ...do something with rowset...
    }
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: Yes this is the answer but only one little observation: to working, the last `SELECT` in mi example must be inside the stmt and not after. If is after (like in mi original question) the result still empty but if i put them inside the stmt ( just before `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` that working good